# How to estimate the money given by a kid when the goal is to purchase a computer game?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is as follows:

Mike and Roger intend to purchase a computer game which has become popular. Assuming Roger gives $P$ times the amount given by Mike and the cost of the computer game is $60$ dollars. Use the following information to find the amount given by Mike.

$$P=\left[\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle a+b]{\frac{\sqrt[a]{2^{b+c}}\cdot\sqrt[b]{2^{a+c}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{a+b}}}{\sqrt[a]{2^{b-c}}\cdot\sqrt[b]{2^{c-a}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{a-b}}}}\qquad\right]^{\frac{c}{2}}$$

and $\frac{b-c}{b}=\frac{c^2}{a^2}$

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{15 dollars}\\
2.&\textrm{12 dollars}\\
3.&\textrm{20 dollars}\\
4.&\textrm{10 dollars}\\
\end{array}$

In my attempt to solve this problem I did the following:

Please note that for brevity and displaying purposes I'm preserving the root as it is indicated above.

$P=\left[\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle a+b]{\frac{\sqrt[a]{2^{b+c}}\cdot\sqrt[b]{2^{a+c}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{a+b}}}{\sqrt[a]{2^{b-c}}\cdot\sqrt[b]{2^{c-a}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{a-b}}}}\qquad\right]^{\frac{c}{2}}$

$P=\left[\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle a+b]{\frac{2^{\frac{b+c}{a}}\cdot 2^{\frac{b+c}{b}} \cdot 2^{\frac{a+c}{c}}}{2^{\frac{b-c}{a}}\cdot 2^{\frac{c-a}{b}}\cdot 2^{\frac{a-b}{c}}}}\qquad\right]^{\frac{c}{2}}$

$P=\left(\left(\frac{2^{\frac{bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)+ab(a+b)}{abc}}}{2^{\frac{bc(b-c)+ca(c-a)+ab(a-b)}{abc}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a+b}}\right)^{\frac{c}{2}}$

$P=\left(\left(2^{\frac{bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)+ab(a+b)-bc(b-c)-ca(c-a)-ab(a-b))}{abc}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a+b}}\right)^{\frac{c}{2}}$

The issue here is what's happening in the numerator of the exponent of $2$:

$bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)+ab(a+b)-bc(b-c)-ca(c-a)-ab(a-b))=2bc^2+2ac^2+2ab^2$

From the initial condition:

$a^2b-a^2c=c^2b$

$2(a^2b-a^2c)+2ac^2+2ab^2=2a^2b+2ab^2=2ab(a+b)$

Then:

$\frac{2ab(a+b)}{abc}=\frac{2(a+b)}{c}$

Then this is:

$P=\left(\left(2^{\frac{2(a+b)}{c}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a+b}}\right)^{\frac{c}{2}}$

$P=2$

Hence it seems that all such fuss was to say $P=2$ hence:

Since it mentions Roger is $P$ times the money given by Mike and all of this equates to $60$ dollars.

$R=PM$

$R=2M$

$2M+M=60$

$3M=60$

$M=20$

Thus I believe that the money given by Mike is $\textrm{20 usd}$?. But is this the only way to approach this problem?.

Comment: Oh, I guess the interpretation is "Roger and Mike give a total of 60 dollars for the game".  In this case, your solution is correct.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Right. I was thinking that they wanted to buy their own individual copies ...

Comment: You can do the algebra a bit faster if you first simplify each pair $\frac{\sqrt[a]{2^{b+c}}}{\sqrt[a]{2^{b-c}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$P=\left[\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle a+b]{\frac{\sqrt[a]{2^{b+c}}\cdot\sqrt[b]{2^{a+c}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{a+b}}}{\sqrt[a]{2^{b-c}}\cdot\sqrt[b]{2^{c-a}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{a-b}}}}\qquad\right]^{\frac{c}{2}}$$

I would simplify
$$\frac{\sqrt[a]{2^{b+c}}}{\sqrt[a]{2^{b-c}}} = \sqrt[a]{2^{2c}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt[b]{2^{a+c}}}{\sqrt[b]{2^{c-a}}} = \sqrt[b]{2^{2a}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt[c]{2^{a+b}}}{\sqrt[c]{2^{a-b}}} = \sqrt[c]{2^{2b}}$$

This simplifies $P$ to
$$P = {\left(\sqrt[a+b]{\sqrt[a]{2^{2c}}\cdot \sqrt[b]{2^{2a}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{2b}}}\right)}^{c/2} = 
{\left(\sqrt[a+b]{\sqrt[a]{2^{c}}\cdot \sqrt[b]{2^{a}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{b}}}\right)}^{c}$$

Then I would turn this into exponential notation:
$${\left(\sqrt[a+b]{\sqrt[a]{2^{c}}\cdot \sqrt[b]{2^{a}}\cdot \sqrt[c]{2^{b}}}\right)}^{c}
= {\left( 2^{c/a}\cdot 2^{a/b} \cdot 2^{b/c} \right)}^{\frac{c}{a+b}}
= 2^{(c/a+a/b+b/c)\cdot \frac{c}{a+b}}$$
and then simplify the exponent to
$$\frac{bc^{2}+a^{2}c + ab^{2}}{abc}\cdot \frac{c}{a+b} = \frac{bc^{2}+a^{2}c+ab^{2}}{ab(a+b)}.$$

Then your equation $\frac{b-c}{b}=\frac{c^2}{a^2}$ tells you
$$bc^{2} = a^{2}(b-c)$$
so
$$\frac{bc^{2}+a^{2}c+ab^{2}}{ab(a+b)} = \frac{a^{2}(b-c)+a^{2}c+ab^{2}}{ab(a+b)} 
= \frac{ab(a+b)}{ab(a+b)} = 1,$$
and so $P = 2^{1} = 2$.

I don't know if this is any easier than the version you had. I don't think it's supposed to be simple.

Comment: Are the $\sqrt[a]{2^{c-a}}$ and $\sqrt[a]{2^{a-b}}$ in the third and fourth equations meant to be $\sqrt[b]{2^{c-a}}$ and $\sqrt[c]{2^{a-b}}$, respectively?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, thank you